# Spring Boot 2.1.1 Issue Accessing Tables in PostgreSQL that are within Oauth2

Tags: spring, postgresql, scala, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am trying to add postgresql support for OAuth2 with Spring Boot after following some examples to clean up my code.

The problem is that I have to add a schema manually to my own schema scripts for the database to create despite specifying certain properties  in the latest Spring Boot. Only after doing so do the tables become recognizable. Also, OAuth2 continues to fail, not finding any table. The issue seems schema related.

I was able to get my own schema to be recognized without specifying one in the entity by disabling auto configuration but cannot figure out why OAuth2 tables are not found unless I use the public schema.

I have added the following properties file with attempts to get Spring boot to recognize my schemas:

```
    server.port=8081

    ## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
    # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database

    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
    spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxx:xxx/oauth2
    spring.datasource.username= xxxxx
    spring.datasource.password= xxxxx
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true;
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = public


# spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
# spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)


spring.thymeleaf.templateResolverOrder=1
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
entitymanager.packagesToScan = com.si.model


logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.guru.springframework.controllers=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema.sql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.template.cache: false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

I have also tried setting the Data Source for each object in the Authorization Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  def oauthDataSource: DataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create.build

  @Autowired
  private var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager = null

  @Bean
  def clientDetailsService = new JdbcClientDetailsService(oauthDataSource)

  @Bean
  def tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(oauthDataSource)

  @Bean
  def approvalStore = new JdbcApprovalStore(oauthDataSource)

  @Bean
  def authorizationCodeServices = new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(oauthDataSource)

  @Bean
  def passwordEncoder(): Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder = new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder()

  @throws[Exception]
  override def configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer): Unit = {
    clients.jdbc(oauthDataSource)
  }

  @throws[Exception]
  override def configure(oauthServer: AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer): Unit = {
    oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
  }

  @throws[Exception]
  override def configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer): Unit = {
    endpoints
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .approvalStore(approvalStore)
        .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore)
  }
}
```

Finally, I set up my web configuration as follows:

```
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private var passwordEncoder: Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder = null

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  def dataSource: DataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create.`type`(classOf[HikariDataSource]).build

  @Bean
  @throws[Exception]
  override def authenticationManagerBean: AuthenticationManager = super.authenticationManagerBean

  @Bean
  @throws[Exception]
  override def userDetailsServiceBean = new JdbcUserDetails()

  @throws[Exception]
  override def configure(web: WebSecurity): Unit = {
    web.ignoring.antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**")
  }

  @throws[Exception]
  override protected def configure(http: HttpSecurity): Unit = {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests
        .antMatchers("/login", "/logout.do")
          .permitAll
        .antMatchers("/**")
          .authenticated
        .and.
        formLogin
          .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
          .usernameParameter("username")
          .passwordParameter("password")
          .loginPage("/login")
        .and
        .logout
          .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout.do"))
      .and
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean)
  }

  @throws[Exception]
  override protected def configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder): Unit = {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean)
      .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
  }
}
```

For some reason, I had to set my schemas to public in the schema script:

```
   drop table if exists public.oauth_client_token cascade;
create table if not exists public.oauth_client_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(255) not null primary key,
  token bytea,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255),
  user_name VARCHAR(255),
  client_id VARCHAR(255)
);

drop table if exists public.oauth_client_details cascade;
CREATE TABLE if not exists public.oauth_client_details (
  client_id varchar(255) NOT NULL primary key,
  resource_ids varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  client_secret varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  scope varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  authorized_grant_types varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  web_server_redirect_uri varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  authorities varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  access_token_validity integer,
  refresh_token_validity integer,
  additional_information varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  autoapprove varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);

drop table if exists public.oauth_access_token cascade;
create table if not exists public.oauth_access_token(
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token bytea,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255),
  user_name VARCHAR(255),
  client_id VARCHAR(255),
  authentication bytea,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(255)
);

drop table if exists public.oauth_refresh_token cascade;
create table if not exists public.oauth_refresh_token(
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token bytea,
  authentication bytea
);
drop table if exists public.authorities cascade;
CREATE TABLE if not exists public.authorities (
  id  bigserial not null primary key,
  authority varchar(255)
);

drop table if exists public.credentials cascade;
CREATE TABLE if not exists public.credentials (
  id  bigserial not null primary key,
  enabled boolean not null,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  password varchar(255) not null,
  version integer
);

drop table if exists public.credentials_authorities cascade;
CREATE TABLE if not exists public.credentials_authorities (
  credentials_id bigint not null,
  authorities_id bigint not null
);

drop table if exists public.oauth_code cascade;
create table if not exists public.oauth_code (
  code VARCHAR(255),
  authentication bytea
);

drop table if exists public.oauth_approvals cascade;
create table if not exists public.oauth_approvals (
    userId VARCHAR(255),
    clientId VARCHAR(255),
    scope VARCHAR(255),
    status VARCHAR(10),
    expiresAt timestamp without time zone,
    lastModifiedAt timestamp without time zone
);
```

Access to the oauth2 tables from the clientDetailsRepository or Oauth2 application results in errors such as the following:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "oauth_client_details" does not exist
```

As a last resort, I set the search path in postgresql to public for my user and still get this error.

**UPDATE**

The following query works in pgadmin4 and is the source of my failure:

```
select client_id, client_secret, resource_ids, scope, authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri, authorities, access_token_validity, refresh_token_validity, additional_information, autoapprove from oauth_client_details order by client_id
```

Any ideas as to why this happens? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is `oauth_client_details` table created in your database ?

Comment: Yes. The program works perfectly with h2 and when I use the jdbc command for authetication. I would like to use the JdbcClientDetailsService and cannot seem to find how I set up postgresql in the past that allowed me to avoid using a public schema for my own tables. I am thinking it is a Spring issue and not an OAuth issue.

Comment: Is the `oauth_client_details` table created in your postgres database?

Comment: As stated, yes. The problem appears to only happen with the oauth library when I do not use the public schema.